# Unable to update HTML table with JavaScript using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner in JavaScript and I would like to print some text out of my table by using `.innerHTML` but it doesn't work. Here's the code:

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td id="tr">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="tr1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="tr2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td id="tr3">&nbsp;</td>
       <td id="tr4">&nbsp;</td>
       <td id="tr5">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td id="tr6">&nbsp;</td>
       <td id="tr7">&nbsp;</td>
       <td id="tr8">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
document.getElementById("tr").innerHTML = "some text";
document.getElementById("tr2").innerHTML = "some text1";
document.getElementById("tr2").innerHTML = "some text2";
document.getElementById("tr3").innerHTML = "some text3";
document.getElementById("tr4").innerHTML = "some text4";
document.getElementById("tr5").innerHTML = "some text5";
document.getElementById("tr7").innerHTML = "some text6";
document.getElementById("tr8").innerHTML = "some text7";
document.getElementById("tr9").innerHTML = "some text8";
</script>
```

Comment: You're fetching `tr2` twice, skipping `tr1` and `tr6`, and there is no `tr9` element ID. Aside from that, I see no issues. What does *"doesn't work"* mean?

Comment: Seems to work fine in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v15updn1/1/) when fixing the issue mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: Which browser are you using, except that you missed `tr1`, `tr6` and you have non-existing `tr9` you can also try to convert `<script>` tag into `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: I am using google chrome

Answer (score 1):

You missed tr6, and tr9 doesn't exist. [Here is a link to a working snapshot of your code](http://jsbin.com/dawano/3/edit?html,js,output).
However, I would recommend you to look up how loops work.

Answer (score 1):

This demo uses a `for`loop to iterate through a NodeList of `<td>`s and assign each `<td>` a string.

Read:

[**querySelectorAll()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

[**Loops and Iteration**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

[**NodeList**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

```js
// Create an array of strings.
// Each string represents what will be in each cell
var content = ['row 1 col 1', 'row 1 col 2', 'row 1 col 3', 'row 2 col 1', 'row 2 col 2', 'row 2 col 3', 'row 3 col 1', 'row 3 col 2', 'row 3 col 3'];

// Create a NodeList of every <td> with querySelectorAll()
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('td');

//Iterate through the Nodelist (cells[]) and assign a string from the array (content[])
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
  cells[i].innerHTML = content[i];
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 3px solid grey;
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
td {
  border: 3px inset black;
  outline: 2px outset grey;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  color: blue;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td id="tr0">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="tr1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="tr2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="tr3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="tr4">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="tr5">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="tr6">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="tr7">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="tr8">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your answer. I have a another question so I have a few conditions do I have to put the array, the loop and the variable in each one of my condition ?

Comment: @tom3883 I'd have to see those conditions and what is expected of them and so forth, to give you a reasonable answer. But *generally* it is better to actually have conditions within the loop so the conditions will apply to each iteration (a full loop) of variables, expressions . etc...

Comment: Ok thank you, so it's better to put the loop over all the conditions and put the array in the conditions ?

Comment: *In general* but there times when a conditional actually drives a loop, once again it all depends...

Comment: @tom3883 Your welcome, sir. If you have anymore trouble, you might want to start another question concerning those conditionals and include a reference to this question. If my answer resolved your question, don't forget to check the green checkmark.